# Python GTK: confirm overwrite dialog blocks filechooser dialog

Tags: python, gtk, filechooser

I have a Gtk.Button that opens a Gtk.FileChooserDialog to save a file. I implemented a Gtk.Dialog for confirmation that pops up when the chosen file name already exists in the target folder to save the file in. If I click on 'cancel' in this dialog the confirmation dialog is destroyed but I cannot use the 'cancel' or 'save' buttons of the Gtk.FileChooserDialog any longer.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="demo")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.button = Gtk.Button()
        self.button.set_image(Gtk.Image(stock=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE))
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Save file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:  # OK button was pressed or existing file was double clicked
            cansave = False
            if os.path.exists(dialog.get_filename()) == True:  # does file already exists?
                dialog2 = DialogSaveFile(self, dialog.get_filename())  # ask to confirm overwrite
                response = dialog2.run()
                if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
                    cansave = True
                else:
                    pass
                dialog2.destroy()
            else:
                cansave = True
            if cansave == True:  # save new file
                open(dialog.get_filename(), "w").close
                dialog.destroy()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            dialog.destroy()

class DialogSaveFile(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, db):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Confirm overwrite", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        self.box = self.get_content_area()
        self.label = Gtk.Label("The file `" + db + "` exists.\nDo you want it to be overwritten?")
        self.box.add(self.label)
        self.show_all()

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Alternatively, setting the `do_overwrite_confirmation` property of the save dialog to `true` should automatically prompt the user for confirmation without further code needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've left the `response = dialog.run()` run loop, you need to either recreate the file dialog, or call `dialog.run()` again to put the file dialog back into a run loop so you can find out what buttons have been pressed.

Restructuring it so the file dialog handler is in a separate function should do the trick (not tested, but you'll get the idea)

```
def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Save file", self,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
    self.handle_file_dialog(dialog)

def handle_file_dialog(self, dialog):
    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:  # OK button was pressed or existing file was double clicked
        cansave = False
        if os.path.exists(dialog.get_filename()) == True:  # does file already exists?
            dialog2 = DialogSaveFile(self, dialog.get_filename())  # ask to confirm overwrite
            response = dialog2.run()
            if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
                cansave = True
                dialog2.destroy()
            else:
                dialog2.destroy()
                # We need to re-run the file dialog to detect the buttons
                self.handle_file_dialog(dialog)
                return
        else:
            cansave = True
        if cansave == True:  # save new file
            open(dialog.get_filename(), "w").close
            dialog.destroy()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        dialog.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works. Only colon missing after 'def handle_file_dialog(self, dialog)'

Comment: Of course, sorry. Not sure why your edit was rejected, but I've fixed it myself

Comment: `if cansave == True` must be `if cansave`, the same for `if os.path.exists(dialog.get_filename()) == True` ⇒ `if os.path.exists(dialog.get_filename())`

Answer (score 2):

You can use :
***dialog.set_do_overwrite_confirmation(True)***
This mode will present a confirmation dialog if the user types a file name that already exists !

---

```
import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="demo")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.button = Gtk.Button()
        self.button.set_image(Gtk.Image(stock=Gtk.STOCK_SAVE))
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(parent=self,title="Save file",
            action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE)
        dialog.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
        dialog.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_OK,Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        
        dialog.set_do_overwrite_confirmation(True)
        # This mode will present a confirmation dialog if the user types a file name that already exists.
        response = dialog.run()
        print(response)
        
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:  # save new file
                open(dialog.get_filename(), "w").close
                dialog.destroy()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:  
                dialog.destroy()
        dialog.destroy()

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```